# Align the cells' content in a Grid in gwt

Tags: java, css, gwt

I am trying to align the content of the Grid-cells in a Grid(1,4). Each cell contains a ListBox. I apply CSS to each column and althougn I can adjust the width I cannot manage to align the ListBoxes in the center. The ListBoxes do not move to the center of the cells even if I apply CSS directly on them instead of the cells. !important does not change anything anything. What could be wrong? Here is the relevant code:

```
Grid mYGrid = new Grid(1, 4);

    mYGrid.addStyleName("mYgrid");
    mYGrid.getCellFormatter().setWidth(0, 0, "150");
    mYGrid.getCellFormatter().setWidth(0, 3, "150");

    mYGrid.setWidget(0, 1, getMonthsList() );
    mYGrid.setWidget(0, 2, getYearsList() );

    mYGrid.getColumnFormatter().setStyleName(1,"monthsCell");
    mYGrid.getColumnFormatter().setStyleName(2,"yearsCell");
```

CSS:

```
.monthsCell{
width:200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

```
.yearsCell{
width:200px;
margin-left: auto  !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are methods in CellFormatter class `setHorizontalAlignment()` and `setVerticalAlignment()`:

```
 Grid grid = new Grid();
 HTMLTable.CellFormatter formatter = grid.getCellFormatter();
 formatter.setHorizontalAlignment(0, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
 formatter.setVerticalAlignment(0, 0, HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

in your css for as a replacement of that method `setVerticalAlignment()` use: `vertical-align:middle;`
and for `setHorizontalAlignment()` use [td align attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp)